# Error of no file bundle1.o found on Mac Catalina

Tags: gcc

Facing no file error on bundle1.o on running make on a repo

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/usr/lib/bundle1.o'
```

system MacOs catalina
version 10.15.3

Already tried installing developer tools with
`xcode-select --install`
which says

```
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates
```

Also tried

```
softwareupdate -i
```

On running a system wide search I found that bundle1.o file does exist in diff locations  but cant be copied and no smlink is getting created for it under /usr/lib

```
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o
/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o
```

no luck so far

Comment: We need to know more about what the makefile includes

Comment: Asterisk makefile. Sample : https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/Makefile.

Comment: As a workaround i commented the _SOLINK+=/usr/lib/bundle1.o in makefile and replaced with other bundle1.o like _SOLINK+=/System/Volumes/Data/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/bundle1.o . After which I started seeing linker error , clang: warning: libstdc++ is deprecated; move to libc++ with a minimum deployment target of OS X 10.9 [-Wdeprecated]
ld: library not found for -lstdc++
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [asterisk] Error 1

Comment: I think the next thing to do is regenerate the makefile by running configure